# Other way to show $ Q, H, M $ are collinear without $BECH$ is a parallelogram (IMO 2015 Problem 3 )

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, plane-geometry

**IMO 2015 Problem 3**

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with $AB\gt AC$. Let $\Gamma$ be its circumcircle, $H$ its orthocenter, and $F$ the foot of the altitude from $A$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Let $Q$ be the point on $\Gamma$ such that $\angle HQA=90^{\circ}$ and let $K$ be the point on $\Gamma$ such that $\angle HKQ=90^{\circ}$. Assume that the points $A,B,C,K$ and $Q$ are all different and lie on $\Gamma$ in this order.
> Prove that the circumcircles of triangles $KQH$ and $FKM$ are tangent to each other.

---

I don't want to find a full answer. Instead, I only want to  show $ Q, H, M $ are collinear.

Let $AE$ be the diameter of $\Gamma$, then $BECH$ is a parallelogram. then, $ H, M , E$ are collinear. $HQ\perp AQ \implies$ $Q, H, M , E$ are collinear.

If  one  don't prove that $BECH$ is a parallelogram, Is there any other way to show $Q, H, M $ are collinear? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Def. of $\Gamma$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Since $OM \perp BC$, we have $OM= \dfrac{AH}{2}$.  Draw the line $EH$.  Also, draw $OM' \parallel AH $ to meet $EH$ at $M'$.  Consequently, $OM'=\dfrac{AH}{2}$, and $OM' \perp BC \implies OM=OM'$.

Comment: who is  the point M'?

Comment: @CFG,add the details.